# Strange characters at beginning of XML AJAX response?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, json

I'm making multiple AJAX calls that returns XML data.  When I get the data back, my success function (in JQuery) tries to turn the XML to JSON (using a plugin).  I was quickly reminded why I can't assume I would be getting VALID XML back from my AJAX request -- because it turns out a few of the XML responses were invalid -- causing the JSON conversion to fail, script to fail, etc...

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to check for
   valid XML on an AJAX response?  Or,
   should I just attempt the JSON
   conversion, then do a quick check if
   the JSON object is valid?
2. In troubleshooting the XML, I found that there are a few strange characters at the VERY beginning of the XML response.  Here's an image from my Firebug:

[image: Bad XML Response]

Should I try to detect and strip the response of those chars or could there possibly be something wrong with my encoding?

Any help is appreciated!  Let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: Those strange characters are known as the Byte Order Mark (BOM) - typically this indicates an issue with text encoding. Didn't post as an answer as it isn't an answer but this might help you find one.

Comment: I'll second what @MrEyes said and, moreover, comment that the BOM should be silently parsed and hidden.  And, if it is displayed, it should come through as a single character.  This indicates that either the character encoding or MIME type coming from your web server is causing the browser to think you're serving Latin-1 data to it.  Could you provide the full header of the response from Firebug?

Comment: @Cons - Response Headersview source
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
Server Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By PHP/5.2.13, ASP.NET
Date Thu, 27 Jan 2011 18:19:14 GMT
Content-Length 42645

Comment: You might want to add `header('Content-type: application/xml');` to your PHP script which generates this XML, then see if it works by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange characters are the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and are actually valid XML, you can most likely just strip them without risk in most circumstances.

Comment: No, just stripping the BOM is hiding a symptom, not fixing the bug.  It'll probably come back to bite you again.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @Jim: Provided the rest of the XML data is read as UTF-8 then the BOM is actually irrelevant **unless** the server providing the data offers a different endian state, as that's all it indicates.

Comment: @Lazarus: Why would you expect the file to partially be interpreted as ISO-8859-x and partially as UTF-8?  That seems so unlikely it's not worth mentioning.  I can't even think of an API that lets you do that on purpose, let alone by accident.

Comment: @Jim: He's seeing the BOM through Firebug, not the API. On that basis it may well be possible for the XML processor that's being called in code to identify the file as UTF-8. Even within XML processors I still find instances of those that cannot deal with the BOM, even though it's part of the spec.

Comment: @Lazarus: I know.  I'm just saying, there's pretty much no software on Earth I can think of that acts the way you assume.  That includes web APIs, file access APIs, string processing APIs and, yes, Firebug too.  If he's seeing the BOM like that, the likelihood of the content being UTF-8 interpreted as ISO-8859-x is approximately 100%, meaning he's going to have problems whenever anything non-ASCII comes up, regardless of whether you strip the BOM or not.  Stripping the BOM is a superficial measure to hide the problem, not a real fix.

Comment: @Jim: Are you saying here that you believe that the JQuery XML parser is the same as the Firebug string viewer in it's assumptions about the character encoding of the string?

Comment: @Lazarus: I'm saying no software decides to partially decode string data as one character encoding then stop halfway through and parse the remainder as a different character encoding.  If the BOM is interpreted incorrectly, then any non-ASCII characters in the same string data will be interpreted incorrectly as well.  It doesn't matter whether this is jQuery, Firebug, or any other software.

Comment: @Jim: At no point have I suggested that to be the case. I have said that many XML parsers do not handle the BOM, UTF-8 encoded or not so it's safe to strip it. The XML **does** need to be parsed as UTF-8 as that's a reasonable assumption, UTF-16 is so infrequently used. So it's fair to strip the BOM and parse the rest of the XML as UTF-8. Now where have I said anything different to that?

Comment: @Lazarus: Did you delete and resubmit your fourth comment or something?  When I responded to it, it didn't say anything about XML processors, it only contained the first sentence, so my responses should be read under that light.

Comment: @Lazarus: After re-reading your comments, it seems to me that they would only make sense if you are assuming Firefox can't handle the BOM.  Is this your assumption?

Comment: @Jim: I don't recall, whether I did or I didn't makes no difference. At no point have I suggested that a function/routine/method would switch character encoding during the processing of a string, it does happen. After all, when parsing XML, you read the header in whatever ASCII-based encoding you like, process it (it will always parse as ASCII) then process the rest of the XML according to the charset value. I do like the idea of software *deciding* to do this rather than the plain old *being programmed* to do so. What a wonderfully unpredictable world that would be.

Comment: @Jim: Firefox isn't handling the BOM in any way shape or form, why would it? The response is just a block of text.

Comment: @Lazarus: You're describing something different, that's two separate bits of data.  The BOM is part of the XML, the HTTP headers are not.

Comment: @Lazarus: If Firefox's treatment of the BOM isn't at issue, which XML parser do you think is mistreating the BOM?

Comment: @Jim: Where do HTTP headers come into this? I think I know what you have misinterpreted but I'll leave it to you to re-read the comments.

Comment: @Jim: It's been clear from the OP posting the question that the issue was not with Firebug's representation of the BOM, it's not been raised as an issue by me or the OP. It's also not a case of mistreatment, more of omission, i.e. they don't expect to see it so don't respond well to it being there. This only became an issue because **you** made an assumption that the XML was being parsed using the same character encoding that Firebug was using to present the AJAX call response data. Jeez, this is hard work.

Comment: @Lazarus: *"After all, when parsing XML, you read the header in whatever ASCII-based encoding you like"*  What headers are you talking about?

Comment: @Jim: The XML header... we are talking about XML here aren't we? It is XML that the OP has pasted a screenshot of...

Comment: @Lazarus: *"Even within XML processors I still find instances of those that cannot deal with the BOM"* - It seemed to me that you were blaming Firefox's handling of the BOM.  *"you made an assumption that the XML was being parsed using the same character encoding that Firebug was using" - No, I made the assumption that if the BOM was breaking things by being misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1, then the rest of the data would similarly be misinterpreted.  That's a reasonable assumption that I've explained above.

Comment: @Lazarus: Since I missed you explaining that you are talking about XML parsers that can't handle the BOM the first time around, I assumed you were taking issue with the idea that character encoding interpretation is consistent from BOM to content.

Comment: @Lazarus: It still leaves me with the question that, if you think that it's a case of the BOM being misinterpreted by an XML parser, *which* XML parser is it that you think is misinterpreting it, if not Firefox's?

Comment: @Lazarus: The XML is being served over HTTP.  If not HTTP headers, what headers are you talking about?

Comment: @Jim: *I made the assumption that if the BOM was breaking things by being misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1, then the rest of the data would similarly be misinterpreted. That's a reasonable assumption that I've explained above.* I disagree, it's not a reasonable assumption and has no basis in respect to the facts present. No one suggested at any point that the BOM was being misinterpreted.

Comment: @Jim: *I assumed you were taking issue with the idea that character encoding interpretation is consistent from BOM to content.* That word again, *assume*.

Comment: @Jim: *which XML parser is it that you think is misinterpreting it, if not Firefox's* Re-read the OPs question and my answer. What leads you to believe that Firefox's XML parser (if indeed it has one) is involved here?

Comment: @Jim: *The XML is being served over HTTP. If not HTTP headers, what headers are you talking about?* Can you see any HTTP headers in the screenshot provided by the OP? Can you see the XML header tag?

Comment: @Jim: I feel you have unfairly marked my answer down based on a single incorrect assumption, I don't think you should change that as my answer doesn't completely address the OPs question so could be seen as fair in that respect. I do feel your answer is based on the same false assumption you made with respect to my answer and would urge you, with your background in web development, to amend it to offer the OP a complete solution to processing his XML responses with or without the BOM. I'd be more than happy for the OP to shift his accepted answer to you at that point. EOM

Comment: @Lazarus: We are obviously talking at cross-purposes and this comment system isn't cut out for in-depth discussions, so I'm calling it a day.  Neither of us are doing a very good job of communicating here - as an example, with your last comment I've finally figured out that you aren't talking about headers at all when you say "header", you're talking about the XML *prologue*. XML doesn't have headers, and it is being transmitted over HTTP which does. Hence the obvious confusion.

Comment: I feel that simply telling somebody to strip the BOM is bad advice that sweeps a problem under the carpet instead of fixing it, hence the vote down.  If your answer wasn't simply "strip it, it's fine" (paraphrased) and actually gave him fair warning, then I'd remove the vote.

Comment: @Jim: Picking on an incorrect term 10 comments and 2 hours into this exchange as the source of the suggested crossed purposes and confusion is stretching it a bit. I'm interested, if you can be coerced to post one more comment, as to what risk you see from stripping the BOM that would require a *fair warning* and what problem it is sweeping under the carpet. After all the BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

It's the UTF-8 [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) when incorrectly interpreted as ISO-8859-1.

You *can't* safely strip this because it's just a symptom of a larger problem.  Your content is encoded as UTF-8.  Somewhere along the way you are decoding it as ISO-8859-1 instead.  If you try to hide the problem by stripping the BOM, you're only setting yourself up for more problems down the line as soon as you start using non-ASCII characters.  The only reason things are even looking *sort-of* right is because ASCII is a common subset of both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1.

Comment: It's also the UTF-8 BOM incorrectly interpreted as ISO-8859-9 and ISO-8859-15.